# How make Ethereum QR-code with Input Data?

Tags: qrcode

how i can make QR code with address, amount, gas price and Input Data?

Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible, I think there's not any limit to QR code and it's not necessary to ask in ethereum stack exchange

Comment: And where i need ask about ethereum qr core?

Answer (score 2):

There's a proposal [EIP 681: URL Format for Transaction Requests](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-681) that will allow to generate a URI for payments.

For example with this URI

```
ethereum:0xABCDabcdABcDabcDaBCDAbcdABcdAbCdABcDABCd?value=1.1e18
```

Will generate this

[image]

Comment: And where in your QR-code Gas Limit and GWEI parameters?

Comment: @Paramedic It is in the specification, you have gasLimit and gasPrice parameters. Also be aware that after two years it is still a draft so a wallet might not have support for it.